# Apples in a greenhouse on a spacestation

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

As a child sometime in the late seventies or very early eighties, I saw a sci-fi movie on TV - there was a scene in a greenhouse, either on a spaceship or space station - you could see stars out the windows, and they were growing apple trees there. A family was serving apple pie, and people were enthusing over it. The family explained that the apples came from Earth, before it was destroyed.  This may have been the pilot for a failed TV show.

Answer (score 6):

That resembles [*Silent Running* (1972)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067756/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), with Bruce Dern.

I don't recall if there was a family and apple pie.  Maybe there was early in the movie, but it has been many decades since I have seen it.

Answer (score 1):

I may have an answer to your question.  I was a professional modelmaker in those years and was approached to make a model spaceship for a television pilot that fits your description.  It was going to be a comedy about an apple pie bakery in space and titled something like "Pie in the Sky." The time period is correct. I did not take the job but recommended another modelmaker to do it. I would be interested to know if you remember anything else?